# Default path of Dll in <DllImport("XYZdll")>

Tags: .net, dllimport

```
<DllImport("XYZ.dll")>
```

Can anybody tell me what is default path of FeeEngineDll.dll in above statement.?

Comment: That would probably be either the path of the AppDomain or the Global Assembly Cache. Try those first. (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ms682586

Comment: Here's a more complete answer to your question:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26710419/3914921

Answer (score 2):

When you using the DllImport attribure you can provide a full or relative path. If you provide no path, the DLL must be in the current path at run time (application working directory and in all paths specified via the PATH environment variable), unless the DLL is loaded by some other means. You are able to convince Windows to find the DLL's if they does not placed in your current directory via the [SetDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

See also: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**Before the system searches for a DLL, it checks the following**

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64
C:\Windows\System32
```

- If a DLL with the same module name is already loaded in memory, the system uses the loaded DLL, no matter which directory it is in. The system does not search for the DLL.
- If the DLL is on the list of known DLLs for the version of Windows on which the application is running, the system uses its copy of the known DLL (and the known DLL's dependent DLLs, if any). The system does not search for the DLL. For a list of known DLLs on the current system, see the following registry key:

  ```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\KnownDLLs
  ```